# Login form and protected route are not working properly; the protected route is not opening after successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

So I have a login form, and when I submit it, it sends the user and password to the server without any problem. The server validates them, and they are approved.

But when the server sends the token to the client, the route still seems to be protected. It gets redirected for like 1/4 a second and then goes back to the `/admin` route. I want it to redirect to the `/tickets` route and stay in the `/tickets` route.

I understand that right now the authentication is incredibly vulnerable to attacks, but I am just trying to use this temporarily to learn a bit more about protected routes and authentication systems. Here is the code:

protected.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

//Create a protected route, that can only be accessed with admin credentials
//For the prototype this will do

function Protected() {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  //the /admin route is the route to the login form.
  return token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='/admin' />;
}

export default Protected;
```

service.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "../Home";
import TicketingSystem from "./TicketingSystem";
import Login from "./Login";
import Protected from "./Protected";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

//Creates protected routes, that will only allow authorized users to access with authorized credentials.
//At this point it will be hard coded, securely into the server

function Service(props) {
    
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/admin' element={<Login />} />
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route element={<Protected />}>
          <Route path='/tickets' element={<TicketingSystem />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
  
export default Service;
```

login.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Grid, Typography, TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./media/login.css";

function Login(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const res = await fetch ('/login-request', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      const { token } = await res.json();
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      props.history.push('/tickets')
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container justifyContent='center' alignItems='center'>
        <div id='login-block'>
          <Typography align='center'>
            <h1 id='login-title'>Admin Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  id='username'
                  name='username'
                  variant='standard'
                  label='username'
                  size='small'
                />
                <br />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <br />
                <TextField
                  id='password'
                  type='password'
                  name='password'
                  variant='standard'
                  label='password'
                  size='small'
                />
                <br />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12}>
                <br />
                <Button id='submit-login-request' variant='contained' type='submit'>
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </form>
            <p id='l1'>The unauthorized use of this route, is illegal.</p>
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

server.js

```js
app.post('/login-request', (req, res, next) => {
  /*  You need to update the token in the front end to true to access tickets,
      But this is insecure, make sure the password is hashed and sent securely
      make sure users cant find vulnerabilities in the login form.
  '
  */

  console.log('recieved login request', req.body.username, req.body.password);
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (username === "admin" && password === "password") {
    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, 'test');
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true });

    // Redirect the user to the /tickets route
    res.status(302).setHeader('Location', '/tickets').end();
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message: "invalid credentials"});
  }
});
```

Is there anyway to make it so once the server sends the response and its approved, it redirects and stays at the `"/tickets"` route?

After some review, I noticed that the localStorage items aren't being created. I believe this has something to do with it, but idk what or why they aren't being created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

You are setting a cookie without sending the token to the client as part of a JSON response. So this `const {token} = await res.json()` will return `undefined` if it doesn't throw an error. And trying to redirect with a header for a request made by JavaScript won't work.

### Solution

A solution, if you want to store the token in local storage, is to change your back end so that you send the token in a JSON, as below. And this should work with the current state of your React code:

```js
app.post("/login-request", (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (username === "admin" && password === "password") {
    const token = jwt.sign({ username }, "test");
    res.status(200).json({ token: token });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "invalid credentials" });
  }
});
```

### Beyond

But say you want to use cookies. In this case, there are multiple changes to be made. On the backend, set the cookie as you already did and send a 200 success message instead of redirecting.

On the React part, you could use a global state, like the  [Context API](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context), to store something about the user being logged in, that you set in the `Login` page, and be able to access in `Protected`. Because an `httpOnly` cookie cannot be accessed by JavaScript on the browser.